# Display all cart items in Paypal checkout

Tags: php, paypal

I want to list all the items purchased in Paypal checkout. I have tried the following code but it does not show items there. It just show the input field in checkout. I am adding snapshot of paypal also. I am first time trying to integrate my site with Paypal.[image]

**Code**

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="testaddabusiness@shop.com">
<!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
  foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value){
    $count=1;
?>
<input type="text" name="item_name_<?php echo $count ?>" value="<?php echo $value['name']  ?>">
 <input type="text" name="item_qty_<?php echo $count ?>" value="<?php echo $value['quantity'] ?>">
 <input type="text" name="amount_<?php echo $count ?>" value="<?php echo $value['price']   ?>">
  <input type="text" name="color_<?php echo $count ?>" value="<?php echo $value['color'] ?>">
  <input type="text" name="size_<?php echo $count ?>" value="<?php echo $value['size']   ?>">
  <input type="text" name="currency_code_<?php echo $count ?>" value="USD">

 <?php
 $count++;
  }}
  ?>
 <!-- Display the payment button. -->
  <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
  <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
   </form>
```

Comment: A few questions for you, OP. Why is `$count` always being set to `1` before displaying each item? (*Additionally, why are you incrementing `count` at the end of the loop?*) Does `$_SESSION['cart']` store a keyed array of a keyed array? If you have access to your server's error log, are you seeing any PHP related errors when you run the code? (*If so, what are they?*) Have you considered just using [the standard PayPal cart implementation](https://goo.gl/wLlRYy)?

Comment: @SpencerDoak I saw this in Paypal documentation that for each item their name should be passed like this `item_1` `item_2`. This is the reason i initialized a counter.

Comment: @SpencerDoak from this link https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/

Comment: OP, thank you, I had never seen that page. Anyway, if that's the case, then one issue with your code is that you are always resetting `$count` to one (1) every time the loop is executed. This means every item's input tag's name attribute will be `*_1` (where `*` is whatever precedes it). To correct this, move `$count=1` before/above the *foreach*-loop and after/above the `if(isset(...))` statement. Because I have not ever worked with handling multiple-item checkouts like this, I do not know if that is your only error, but that is definitely one problem with the code.

Comment: @SpencerDoak Thanks for pointing my code mistake. But it didn't made any changes in paypal checkout. It is still as same as the above image shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item_name_x` only applies to Cart Upload command.

You need to change `cmd` value to "`_cart`", and add another variable called `upload` and value of `1`.

Here is an example:

```
cmd = _cart
upload = 1
amount_1 = 0.01
item_name_1 = Test Item
item_number_1 = 123
currency_code = USD
...
```

After that, your code should work.

For more information, visit [HTML Variables of PayPal Payment Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).

Comment: it helped me :) But can you please tell me the variable names to pass `size` and `color` as well. I didn't find the answer in documentation

Comment: @tabia For that, you have to use `on0` or `on1`, which is for label. As for value, you will use `os0` or `os1`.  For example, if `on0` is `size`, `os0` would be `large`. Same goes for `color`. It is all documented on the link I posted above.